# Picard–Lindelöf theorem - problem with a step in the proof

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem#Detailed_proof

I've been analyzing the proof of existence and uniqueness in ODE solutions given in the above. I can't understand how does the factorial pop up in the denominator. Let me write down the specifics.
We have a system of linear differential equations $y'=F(x,y)$ where $y=(y_1(x) , \dots , y_n (x))$. We are trying to show that
$$ \Phi_k(x) = \eta + \int_\xi^xF(t,\Phi_{k-1}(x))dt$$
where $\Phi(\xi)=\eta$ - initial value basically. We restrict ourselves to a set
$T=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}:|x-\xi|<a,|y-\eta|<b,\,\,\,a,b>0 \}$
were Lipschitz condition is satisfied wrt $y$ which in turn gives $$|F(x,y_b)-F(x,y_a)|\leq L|y_b-y_a|, L>0$$
We define $M=\max_{(x,y)\in T}|F(x,y)|$ and we start with $\Phi_0(x)=\eta$.
I understand this:
$$|\Phi_1 - \Phi_0| = \left | \int_{\xi}^x F(t,\Phi_0 (t))dt  \right | \leq \left | \int_{\xi}^x |F(t,\Phi_0 (t))|dt  \right |\leq \left | \int_{\xi}^x Mdt  \right |=M|x-\xi|$$
Now I have no idea where does the $2!$ come from in the end of the next step:
$$|\Phi_2 - \Phi_1| = \left | \int_{\xi}^x [F(t,\Phi_1 (t))-F(t,\Phi_0 (t))]dt  \right |\leq  \left | \int_{\xi}^x |F(t,\Phi_1 (t))-F(t,\Phi_0 (t))|dt  \right |\textrm{(and from Lipschitz)} \leq  \left | \int_{\xi}^x L|\Phi_1 (t))-\Phi_0 (t)|dt  \right |\leq \frac{LM|x-\xi|^2}{2}$$
$M,L$ are just constants and so seems $|x-\xi|$, so we should be left with:
$$\left | \int_{\xi}^x L|\Phi_1 (t))-\Phi_0 (t)|dt \right | \leq LM|x-\xi|\int_{\xi}^x dt=LM|x-\xi|^2$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because the bound is true for all upper boundaries $x$. Thus you replace in the integrand
$$
|Φ_1(t))−Φ_0(t)|\le M|t−ξ|
$$
Then integration of this linear function gives $\int_ξ^x |t−ξ|dt = \frac12|t−ξ|^2$.